# \cite appears with [number] and horrible apex

Tags: bibliographies

sorry if my question sounds a bit dumb, but I'm struggling to get a good typeset about `\cite`.

I created a simple bibliography in my article, but when I typeset it, the `\cite{example}` appears as `[1]` with a horrible apex "example". How to hide it?

PS: I don't want to make use of a .bib reference file, just keep everything in the same .tex file.

This is what I get:

[image]

Example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{showkeys} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\linespread{1.3} 



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduzione}

Lorem ipsum \cite{example} is great.

\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{example} 
Parker Peter {\em How I became the Spiderman} BMJ 1991; 317(5432):   61–65

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The output of `\cite` depends on packages and on bibliography style(s).

Comment: Remove `showkeys` -- this package just shows the bib - key responsible for a particular cite. I recommend the use of `bibtex` or `biblatex` rather than typing the bibliography directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main cause is the `showkeys` package -- it just relates the `\cite` command with the relevant key from the bibliography, as a hint which `\cite` refers to which key in the printed document.

Adding `final` option to the documentclass option will remove the effect of `showkeys` or just comment out `\usepackage{showkeys}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,oneside,12pt,final]{book}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{showkeys} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\linespread{1.3} 



\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Introduzione}

Lorem ipsum \cite{example} is great.


\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{example} Parker Peter {\em How I became the Spiderman} BMJ 1991; 317(5432):   61–65
\end{thebibliography}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to use a .bib reference. I need to keep the bibliography in the same .tex file

Comment: @Nemomnis: I removed the `.bib` stuff. You can add `final` to the documentclass and it will switch off `showkeys` effect